vimtex compiler not using xelatex even after being configured properly?
I am using the following configuration for vimtex plugin to use xelatex:
vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
  executable = 'latexmk',
  options = {
    '-xelatex',  -- Specifies the use of XeLaTeX
    '-file-line-error',
    '-synctex=1',
    '-interaction=nonstopmode',
  },
}

And my overall configuration looks like following:
-- Enable filetype detection, plugins, and indentation
vim.cmd('filetype plugin indent on')

-- Enable syntax highlighting
vim.cmd('syntax enable')


-- Configure the compiler for VimTeX
vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
  executable = 'latexmk',
  options = {
    '-xelatex',  -- Specifies the use of XeLaTeX
    '-file-line-error',
    '-synctex=1',
    '-interaction=nonstopmode',
  },
}

-- Configure the viewer method for VimTeX
vim.g.vimtex_view_method = 'skim'
vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_sync = 1
vim.g.vimtex_view_skim_activate = 1

vim.g.maplocalleader = ','

When I start the live compilation (using ,, in command mode) for my tex file, I still get the following error:
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty|45 error| Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of "latex" or "pdflatex".
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty|45 error| Emergency stop.
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty|45 error| ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

What am I doing wrong? I checked the variable value of vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk, and it has the one provided in the configuration.

I am sorry, my pdf file was missing the vimtex-tex-program directive at the top, adding the following to the top of my pdf file worked:
% !TeX program = xelatex

...

